# Optimize XML parsing to use lesser memory

Tags: python, xml, optimization, xml-parsing, large-data

I am currently doing a parsing of a bunch of large XML files using:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

and this is my function:

```
def xmlfilter(input_file):
    print('Processing file: ' + input_file)
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file = input_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    packagebody = root.find('./PackageBody')

    # reverse traversal to prevent skipping nodes after removal and avoid another loop
    for invvehicle in list(reversed(packagebody)):
        try:
            for port in invvehicle.findall('./PortfolioList/Portfolio'):
                for hold in port.find('./Holding'):
                    for rawitem in hold:
                        # if ID belongs to list above, proceed to next invvehicle
                        if rawitem.tag == 'ID' and rawitem.text in IDs:
                            print(rawitem.text + ' under ' + invvehicle.attrib['_Id'])
                            raise SkipNode

            # if no ID from list above is found, remove the node
            packagebody.remove(invvehicle)

        except SkipNode:
            continue

    ET.ElementTree(root).write(queuedir + "filtered_" + input_file)
    ET.ElementTree(root).write(ftpdir + "filtered_" + input_file)
```

When parsing a 10gb worth of file, it maxes out the machine's memory. Is there anything I can do with the above script so I can lessen the memory usage? And if possible, to also make the processing faster?

I would appreciate it if there will be some solution/answer that only utilizes the above library. But if there is a better library that manages the memory way better than the above option, then please do suggest as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lxml` is usually more space efficient than `ElementTree` because it backends to the C based libxml2. You should be able to write a single XPATH to select the nodes you want. That will remove the need to reverse your delete list. I wasn't sure how to deal with `in IDs` so I wrote an XPATH extension function that checks if the XML text is in a set of values you supply. This class is initialized with your ids and its `__call__` method is called by XPATH.

I think your XPATH would be something like

```
"PackageBody/*[not(is_in_ids(PortfolioList/Portfolio/Holding/ID/text()))]"
```

but I don't have your data to test against, so that's just a guess. I wrote a simpler example to demonstrate.

test.xml

```
<root>
        <a><b>one</b><b>five</b><b>two</b><b>seven</b></a>
</root>
```

test.py

```
from lxml import etree
 
class IsInIDs:

    """lxml XPath extension function checks if single value
    given is in the given list of ids"""
    def __init__(self, list_of_ids):
        self.ids = set(list_of_ids)
        
    def __call__(self, context, value):
        return len(value) and value[0].strip() in self.ids 

my_ids = ["one", "two", "three"]

ns = etree.FunctionNamespace(None)
ns['is_in_ids'] = IsInIDs(my_ids)

doc = etree.parse("test.xml")
for item in doc.xpath("a/b[not(is_in_ids(text()))]"):
    item.getparent().remove(item)

print(etree.tostring(doc))
```

Comment: Hey, that's a very good approach. This only took 38 seconds which the previous one took ~55sec for a 1GB file. Although I noticed that compared to my loop approach which consumed a peak of 6.6GB memory, this faster script consumed 9.4GB which is a substantial increase and is my main issue right now. Is there no other way that will improve the memory usage when parsing large XML files?

Comment: Okay, that didn't go as expected. There is "streaming XSLT" which would do it with far less memory. https://saxonica.com does it but I don't think its available in a free edition. The spec has been out for a long time but I don't know who supports it. You could also use SAX which processes XML parsing events. That's a bigger lift with code, but you could hold invvehicle in memory until you decide its a good one to stream out. And there are noSQL XML databases out there. If you could get your data into one of those, it may have the facilities you want.

Comment: Hey @tdelaney, this was still a big help. This solution will also fit to my other issues as of now so you deserve at least a thanks. Thank you very much for the solution above.